# JSON parsing with Gson JSONObject contains list of JSON Arrays

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

How to convert the following json response to Java object using gson library.
{

```
"status":"Success",
"result":{
    "VenuereviewDet":[
        {
            "user_profile_imgPath":"",
            "reviewDet_reviewtxt":"New review",
            "reviewDet_reviewsts":"0",
            "reviewDet_name":"jP",
            "reviewDet_reviewdatetime":"Wednesday 23rd of July 2014 07"
        },
        {
            "user_profile_imgPath":"",
            "reviewDet_reviewtxt":"1kjdkgnkdfmgm",
            "reviewDet_reviewsts":"0",
            "reviewDet_name":"sreekanth",
            "reviewDet_reviewdatetime":null
        }
    ],
    "venueimages":[
        {
            "venueimages_thumbimg":"http:\/\/localhost\/app\/images\/videothumb\/JamonJamon_1.jpg",
            "venueimages_image":"http:\/\/localhost\/app\/images\/videothumb\/JamonJamon_1.jpg",
            "venueimages_id":"51",
            "venuedet_id":"10"
        },
        {
            "venueimages_thumbimg":"http:\/\/localhost\/app\/images\/videothumb\/http:\/\/localhost\/app\/images\/videothumb\/JamonJamon_2.jpg",
            "venueimages_image":"http:\/\/localhost\/app\/images\/videothumb\/JamonJamon_2.jpg",
            "venueimages_id":"52",
            "venuedet_id":"10"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

How to convert this JSON response to Java Object using gson library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu need to make following classes First

```
class VenuereviewDet
    {
        String user_profile_imgPath;
        String reviewDet_reviewtxt;
        String reviewDet_reviewsts;
        String reviewDet_name;
        String reviewDet_reviewdatetime;
    }

    class Venueimages
    {
        String venueimages_thumbimg;
        String venueimages_image;
        String venueimages_id;
        String venuedet_id;
    }
    class Data
    {
        ArrayList<VenuereviewDet> VenuereviewDet;
        ArrayList<Venueimages> venueimages;
    }
    class FinalRespone
    {
        String status;
        Data result;
    }
```

And Then

```
FinalRespone response=gson.fromJson(jsonResponse,FinalRespone.class);
```

Now let me explain you.

- In your respone there is a object named result. So n you class there has to be a object of class which can handle array of VenuereviewDet and Venueimages. Becuase those keys are coming as arrays.
- SO FinalResponse is class which has status and data inside. and Data class has two member data which are nothing but Objects of ArrayList of some classes.
- WIth GSON the only problem is creating lot of model classes. The moment you break your response in class structure. It becomes easy for you.

Let me know if you still face problem with GSON

Comment: Getting NullPointerException when i tried to print the size of Venueimages list size.
response.result.Venueimages.size();

Comment: Edited the answer. Changed ArrayList<Venueimages> Venueimages; to ArrayList<Venueimages> venueimages; V was in capital.

Comment: You have to keep same object name as its in api'skey. You can also you @SerializedName("Key from API") to keep varibale name and key name separate

Answer (score 0):

Using Google's [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) you could convert json string to java object with this lines of code.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

List listObject = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse,ArrayList.class);
```

or

```
YourObject[] objectArray = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse,YourObject[].class);
```

since i think you might need the "result" : "succes" you can have this structure

```
public class MyObject{

   private String result

   //where you store your VenuereviewDet array and venuimages array
   private ArrayList result;

  //getters setters

}
```

then convert to java object

```
MyObject objectArray = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse,MyObject.class);
```

Comment: How the class structure should look like